# Why is the transaction fee a multiple of the amount I want to send?

Tags: transaction-fees, blockchain.info

I tried sending 0.0001 BTC from my blockchain.info wallet.  It deducted 0.0009 BTC from my account, including a 0.0008 BTC is transaction fee.

Is it correct that the transaction fee is 8 times larger than the amount sent?

Comment: Bitcoin transaction fees are based mainly on the number of *bytes* in the transaction; they're not a percentage of the amount transacted.  If you had sent BTC 1000, you'd still have paid BTC 0.0008.  Bitcoin is not really intended for lots of very small transactions.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Then why is "cheap micropayments" explicitly listed as a feature?  (See http://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-for-developers)

Comment: @cHao: "Micro" is a relative term.  They qualify it with "as low as a few dollars".  The proposed transaction of 0.0001 BTC is only about 0.08 USD at today's prices.

Comment: @NateEldredge: And $.08 falls well within the realm of any meaningful use of the term in the real world.  If "as low as a few dollars" is the cutoff for a "micropayment" in BTC, then clearly someone over there doesn't quite get what a micropayment actually *is*.

Comment: @cHao: The whole site is on Github; if you have better language in mind, why not submit a pull request?  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/blob/master/_translations/en.yml

Comment: @NateEldredge: Because it's not my job.  I don't care about Bitcoin or its success yet.  I have no BTC, and haven't decided yet whether it's even worth the time and trouble to invest.  And from my POV, misinformation isn't a bug to fix -- it's a red flag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12567/discussion-between-nate-eldredge-and-chao)

Comment: There are plenty other crypto-coins that are worth less than Bitcoin and/or with lower transaction fees. As of late a lot of people are sending dogecoins as tips for "good deeds" or to compensate writers of interesting articles. With dogecoins about 100 satoshis and bitcoin around USD $830, sending 250 doges would give receiver around 20 cents of dollar, transaction fees of just 1 doge - now THAT is a very cheap micro payment by all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

That's the recommended fee, the recommended fee is like the minimum amount to get your transaction included in a block ASAP. You should be able to set fees, but for small amounts like that a fee that large is common, remember, miners can only include so many transactions a block every 10 minutes, so they pick the transactions with the largest fee and smallest txn size.

Answer (score 1):

The details about bitcoin fees are explained [here](http://bitcoinfees.com). In short: If you don't pay fees for small amounts, it takes longer until your transactions are included in a block and thus confirmed (to avoid "dust" spam). For blockchain.info you can click on "Send Money" and then "custom" to specify 0 BTC for "Miners Fee". I don't see a problem with this, because they get 25 BTC anyway for mining a block.